# Install4j deletes jre\bin folder during installation

Tags: install4j

I am using Install4j 6.1.1 to create a new installer that must be smart enough to support 3 installation scenarios:

1. Create a new installation
2. Upgrade an existing installation
3. Upgrade an existing installation that was created using an InstallAnywhere installer

Scenarios 1 and 2 function correctly. With scenario 3 there is a problem with installing a new jre.

If my installer finds an old non-Install4j instance, it invokes the previous version's uninstaller before proceeding with a new install. This seems to work just fine. However, the new bundled JRE is not being installed properly. The Install Files action copies the JRE to the install folder, and then the deletes the bin folder. This results in a corrupted installation that will not execute. I can see this happen- if I open the JRE subfolder during install I can see the jre's lib and bin folders get created and then watch the bin folder get deleted. The jre\lib folder remains. There does not seem to be anything in the installation log to explain what's happening.

Any idea what would cause a bundled JRE to partially install?

Comment: Is this on Windows? Probably a launcher is still running that uses this JRE.

Comment: It's on Windows 7. It's the JRE that is bundled with the installer and I don't think anything is using it. How can I verify this?

Comment: With the JPS tool from the JDK or with process explorer (google it) on the rt.jar file of the bundled JRE.